# Eclipse - scroll back after viewing definition

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, is it possible to use some key combination to "go back" after control+clicking a field or method to view its definition, so that I don't have to scroll back down whenever I do so?

Answer (score 2):

- You can use "Back" button on the toolbar (its icon is a yellow arrow pointing to the left).
- Alternatively, use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> to get the same result.
- Use "Forward" toolbar button (yellow, right-pointing arrow icon) or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Roght Arrow</kbd> to go forward.